# definition of tables has changed

Tags: mysql

I am currently learning mysql and something has come up I wasn't expecting and unsure if this is normal. I created my tables etc. I added foreign keys to link them together for efficient JOINS. everything was fine upon using the DESC statement I could view which columns where `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `PRIMARY KEYS AND FOREIGN KEYS`.

But I then did a `CREATE VIEW` statement to make an alias for my tables to make queries a lot quicker and I then used the reverse engineer to create a diagram model on workbench. Since doing this I have noticed when I use the DESC statement, the keys column is blank as is the extra column which should show `auto_increment` for my `primary key column`.
On this table, `Power_id` should be `PRIMARY and AUTO_INCREMENT`.
t`urbo_id, drive_id and car_id` should all show MUL as they are `FOREIGN KEYS`.

No idea why this has happened?

```
Field       Type    Null  Key   DEFAULT   Extra
Power_id    int(11) NO          0   
engine  varchar(50) YES         NULL
power   varchar(50) YES         NULL
litre   varchar(50) YES         NULL
turbo_id    int(11) YES         NULL
car_id      int(11) YES         NULL
drive_id    int(11) YES         NULL
```

Comment: What engine did you use to create your tables? i.e. Myisam, Innodb, etc

Comment: Can you post the result of `show create table 'table_name'` and `show create view 'view_name'`?

Comment: im using Innodb. show create table results :

Comment: car_power CREATE TABLE `car_power` (
   `Power_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `engine` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `power` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `litre` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `turbo_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `car_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `drive_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`Power_id`),
   KEY `car_choice_car_id_fk` (`car_id`),
   KEY `turbo_id` (`turbo_id`),
   KEY `drive_id` (`drive_id`),

Comment: CONSTRAINT `car_choice_car_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `car_choice` (`car_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `car_power_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`turbo_id`) REFERENCES `turbo` (`turbo_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `car_power_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`drive_id`) REFERENCES `drive` (`drive_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: show create view statement: cp CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `cp` AS select `car_power`.`Power_id` AS `Power_id`,`car_power`.`engine` AS `engine`,`car_power`.`power` AS `power`,`car_power`.`litre` AS `litre`,`car_power`.`turbo_id` AS `... utf8 utf8_general_ci